# Biopython: MMTFParser can't find distances between atoms

Tags: biopython

I'm using biopython to find the distance between the C alpha atoms of two residues and I keep getting an error. Here's my code and the error:

```

```
>>> from Bio.PDB.mmtf import MMTFParser
>>> structure = MMTFParser.get_structure_from_url('4mne')
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain A is discontinuous at line 0.
  PDBConstructionWarning)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain D is discontinuous at line 0.
  PDBConstructionWarning)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain E is discontinuous at line 0.
  PDBConstructionWarning)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain F is discontinuous at line 0.
  PDBConstructionWarning)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain H is discontinuous at line 0.
  PDBConstructionWarning)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain B is discontinuous at line 0.
  PDBConstructionWarning)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain C is discontinuous at line 0.
  PDBConstructionWarning)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/StructureBuilder.py:89: PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain G is discontinuous at line 0.
  PDBConstructionWarning)
>>> for c in structure.get_chains():
...     if c.get_id() == 'B':
...             chain = c
...
>>> chain
<Chain id=B>
>>> CAatoms = [a for a in chain.get_atoms() if a.id == 'CA']
>>> for a in CAatoms:
...     for b in CAatoms:
...             distance = a-b
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Atom.py", line 124, in __sub__
    diff = self.coord - other.coord
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
>>>
```

```

Does this have something to do with the "get_structure_from_url" method of the MMTFParser? 
I've tried this with PDBParser().get_structure and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Biopython's atom class has a custom subtraction method.

From the [source code](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/Atom.py):

```
def __sub__(self, other):
    """Calculate distance between two atoms.
    :param other: the other atom
    :type other: L{Atom}
    Examples
    --------
    >>> distance = atom1 - atom2
    """
    diff = self.coord - other.coord
    return numpy.sqrt(numpy.dot(diff, diff))
```

<strike>For MMTFParser this feature seems to be missing but you can easily do it yourself.</strike>

MMTFParser reads the coordinates as a list (`init_atom(str(atom_name), [x, y, z] ...`, [line 53](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/mmtf/DefaultParser.py)), unlike PDBParser which reads the coordinates as a Numpy array (`coord = numpy.array((x, y, z), "f")`, [line 187](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/PDBParser.py)).

In order to get the distance you can convert the coordinate lists to a Numpy array and then calculate the distance.

```
import numpy as np
distance = np.linalg.norm(np.array(a.coord) - np.array(b.coord))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if the MMTFParser didn't have that feature, or if it was just me doing something wrong.

Comment: @M.Iyer: See the updated answer, it's an implementation error, I'll open a pull request in the next few days.

Comment: @M.lyer: the bug fix has been implemented and will probably be part of one the next versions: https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/1456

Comment: Thank you. I found that feature very helpful so it would be great if MMTFParser had it.

Comment: @M.lyer: the latest version should have it. You can download it from github.